# Problem with embedding QML into resource Qt application

Tags: qt, embedded-resource, qml

I have some problem with embedding my QML component into resource of my application.

I have some gui.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 480
    height: 525
    color: "#ffff00"
}
```

My dirs

```
\main.cpp
\gui.qml
```

I tried run it:

```
view = new QDeclarativeView(m_GUI);
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gui.qml"));
```

But i catch:

```
qrc:/gui.qml: File not found
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thank all )
I solved it.

In resource i have "Prefix" for the root path.

```
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyPrefix/gui.qml"));
```

Comment: I noticed that with this approach whenever I change the QML file I have to rebuild the project so that the changes are included in QRC (otherwise it uses the old version). Maybe some smaller action would suffice but for sure just running the application doesn't refresh the resources and uses the old ones. (On the other hand setting source to the file directly with `QUrl::fromLocalFile` always sees the changes on QML without building anything.) Do you know what to set to have to QRC rebuild after modifying QML?